# How come I could spend 1.5 WETH, even though I only wrapped 1 ETH?

Tags: nft, wrapped-tokens

On opensea, I converted (wrapped) 1 ETH to 1 WETH, which is equal to 2 x 0.5 WETH = 1 WETH.
I then spent 0.5 WETH on 3 items = 1.5 WETH, which is greater than the amount I had.

how is this even possible, and where is the WETH balance even kept, in my MetaMask wallet (i don't see it there) or in my opensea account?

Comment: Please link you account or the transactions. What you are describing is not possible.

Comment: but it did. cannot share the transactions out of privacy so i will wait for someone who knows